# Socket.io with NGINX and https2

Tags: node.js, nginx, https, socket.io, http2

I have `node.js` app which is served by `NGINX`. I can't connect socket.io and keep getting 404 for POST requests to establishing a connection.

It's working locally, so it must be an `NGINX` problem.

```
  # HTTP - redirect all requests to HTTPS:
  server {
     listen 80;
     listen [::]:80;
     return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }
  # HTTPS - proxy requests on to local Node.js app:
  server {
     listen 443 ssl http2;
     server_name example.com;
     ssl on;
     ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
     ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
     ssl_session_timeout 5m;
     ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
     ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
     ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
     location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
     }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Which nginx version you are using? It might not support HTTP2 yet.

Comment: It's newest version. HTTP2 works fine, it's a problem with NGINX config for socekts.

Comment: Do you have initialized socket.io and set to listen like this:
var io = app.io; io.listen( server ); ?

Comment: @iubema That's exactly how I have it.

Answer (score 2):

Since Websockets are using the `Upgrade` header introduced in HTTP 1.1, you'll need to specifically use this protocol in your route and set the `Connection` header to `upgrade`.

You'll also need to specify a `proxy_pass` directive with a unique name.

Your config would be something like that:

```
upstream sockets {
  server localhost:8080;
}

# HTTP - redirect all requests to HTTPS:
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS - proxy requests on to local Node.js app:
server {
     listen 443 ssl http2;
     server_name example.com;
     ssl on;
     ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
     ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
     ssl_session_timeout 5m;
     ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
     ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
     ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

     location / {

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;

        proxy_pass http://sockets;

        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
     }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I'll try it soon as possible and give you feedback.

Comment: My other API calls which are not socets should `proxy_pass` on `http://127.0.0.1:8080`, so can have multiple locations? One location handling socets and one normal requests?

Comment: Just like the sockets, you can rename the upstream to something different than `sockets` to something like `website` to be more coherent. That's what I use too ;)